# Redux Form HandleSubmit data empty

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

**Problem**

Form's data are not getting passed to `handleSubmit()` function upon submission. What am I doing wrong?

**Form**

```
import React from 'react'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
export const fields = ['email', 'password']

const validate = (values) => {
  const errors = {}
  return errors
}

export class SignUp extends React.Component {
  props: Props;

  render() {
    const {
      fields: { email, password },
      handleSubmit
    } = this.props

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <div>
            <input type="email" placeholder="you@gmail.com" {...email}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password</label>
          <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" {...password}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

SignUp = reduxForm({
  form: 'SignUp',
  fields,
  validate
})(SignUp)

export default SignUp
```

**Form's Parent**

```
export class SignUpView extends React.Component {
  props: Props;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this)
  }

  onSignUp(data) {
    console.log(data) <-- data is just an empty Object {}
    this.props.signUp({
      email: email,
      password: password
    });
  }

  render() {
    var fields = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Sign Up Form</h1>
        <SignUpForm
          fields={fields}
          onSubmit={this.onSignUp}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `handleSubmit` from this.props, but you are passing in `onSubmit`.

You could do something like the following to remap it:

```
const {
  fields: { email, password },
  onSubmit: handleSubmit
} = this.props
```

This is shorthand for (skipping the fields bit):

```
const handleSubmit = this.props.onSubmit;
```

Comment: `redux-form` package expects to receive `handleSubmit` as props and it internally called `onSubmit(handleSubmit())` I think

Comment: Handlesubmit is fine, but you need to remap onSubmit (your input prop) onto handleSubmit before passing it down the line

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing in any fields prop, as those are defined (properly) in your form component.

```
<SignUpForm
  fields={fields} // <----- REMOVE THIS
  onSubmit={this.onSignUp}
/>
```

What it looks like you are trying to do is to set the initial values to `''`. If you want to do that, you could do:

```
<SignUpForm
  initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
  onSubmit={this.onSignUp}
/>
```

But that is not necessary, as `''` is already the default in `v5.x`.